# How do bottom align an element so it can expand unrestricted vertically?

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

On one of my pages I have the following structure which I am attempting to use as a sort of tooltip style behavior. The "child" element is hidden until the "container" element is clicked. What I am trying to do is align the child above the actual container but my issue is the child can have a variable height so I don't know how to align it correctly.

Here is my concept code:

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div id="child">
        <p>Dynamic text so</p>
        <p>I never know the</p>
        <p>expected height</p>
    </div>
</div>


#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #red;
}
```

Essentially what I want to do is align the bottom of the #child with the top of the #container so that the container can expand upward unrestructed depending on the value of the content. This isn't quite producing the expected result though as you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tA9wr/

It only works because I have specifically set the #child bottom value to 130px. If the content inside the #child changes in height at all this will no longer work. Here is a quick MS Paint version of what I want to happen as the #child's hight varies:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Bzt.png

Any ideas how I can accomplish what I want?

Comment: Is it as simple as switching the order of <p>Some text</p> and #child?  Or am I missing something? (http://jsfiddle.net/tA9wr/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to position the div absolutely (relative to parent) and set the bottom property to 100% (which means full height of the parent) to place it at the top of the container:

```
#container {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative; /*set container to relative */
}

#child {
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute; /* position relative to container*/
    bottom: 100%; /*place bottom at top of container*/
}
```

This will make `#child` expand upwards

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tA9wr/2/)**

Comment: Perfect! Simple as well. Thank you for your help!